# Navigation Drawer Activity move from fragments to activities and return

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have a `navigation drawer activity` with `fragments` and I will send each `fragment` to an `activity`. I have a problem if I select option 3 of my menu that is a `fragment` that will send me to an `activity`, but when I return with the Back button, it sends me to option 1, what I want is that I return to option 3.
How can I change this?
I tried to do it by `parentActivity` but it did not work
Thank you.

My `navigation drawer activity`with`fragments`
[image]

When I click on the button, it sends me to an `activity` that is this
And in the `activity` I have a `toolbar` to return and what I want is to return to option 3 and not to 1.

What do I need to do in my code or what can I place?

[image]

[image: activity]

My fragment code option 3

```
public class Mis_Aliados extends Fragment {

Button boton;

public Mis_Aliados() { }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.persona_mi_perfil, container, false);

    boton=view.findViewById(R.id.buton);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActividadEx.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    return view;
}

}
```

My `activity` code

```
public class ActividadEx extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pruebaactividad);

    Toolbar toolbarback=findViewById(R.id.include);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarback);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Activity");
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
}
```

Comment: OK.. show your Button Fragment code.

Comment: Here is my code I have edited the question

Comment: Show your code when you press Back Button on `ActividadEx`

Comment: Ok sir I've put it ActividadEx

Answer (score 0):

In your `ActividadEx`  add this method to handle toolbar back button press

I'm putting 1 intent extra to make sure you want to open Option 3 when you are back to Navigation drawer Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavgationDrawerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("openOption3", true);
            startActivity(intent); 
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**On NavigationDrawerActivty inside onCreate()**

you can check if Bundle has data or not. If its empty you can open Option1 fragment.

If it has data check it. and open Option3 Fragment.

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.getBoolean("openOption3", false)) {
            //Use Fragment Transaction to Open Option 3 Fragment
        } else {
            //Open Option 1 Fragment Or any other Fragment
        }
    } else {
        //Open Option 1 Fragment Or any other Fragment
    }
```

Feel free to comment if you've any queries.

Comment: Thank you for the code sir I have put it as you said and check but I still send to option 1.
I'm a beginner in this, so I really do not know what else to do.

Comment: if you have added parent activity of `ActividadEx` . remove it. and Try

Comment: I already checked and I do not have parentActivity and it continues with the same thing.

Comment: @CarlosMario have you added `onBackPressed()` in `ActividadEx` ?